# Get multiple strings from a text by using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following set of strings in a PHP file.

```
echo '<div class="alert"><b>',__('ERROR!'),'</b> ',__('Please fix following errors!'),'</div>';
echo sprintf(__('hello %s'), $name);
___('Hello');
```

`__()` function returns string and `___()` function echo's a string. I have written a regex to grab text in between `__('')` or `___('')` but it's not working properly.

Here is my regex

```
if(preg_match_all("#(__{2,3}(\((.*)\),|;))#",$text, $matches))
```

and output I get is:

```
__('ERROR!'),' ',__('Please fix following errors!'), (Incorrect result)
__('hello %s'),
```

For the `___()` function I am using quantifier _{2,3} but it's not picking up this function. How do I get the string only from the functions?

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to read with actual function names instead of varying numbers of underscores...

Comment: These are the actual names, I am using them for translation purpose

Comment: Hah, fair enough then.

Comment: to be honest this is wrong... cause you can have something like: __('test error(error #43), some other text here...')... that means your function will stop after 43... you need to get it more like this `(_{2,3})(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))+\))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `__{2,3}`. `a{n,m}` repeats the **previous item** between n and m times. So `__{2,3}` matches an underscore followed by 2 or 3 underscores. You're trying to match an underscore repeated 2 or 3 times, so use `_{2,3}` instead.

Then, you're using `,|;` to match a comma or a semicolon. This does not work as you expect. `|` is used to specify alternatives. For example, `(foo|bar)` matches either `foo` **or** `bar`. In your regex, you're using `(\((.*)\),|;)`, and this will mean match `\((.*)\),` or `;` -- which is not what you want. To match a `,` or `;`, use a character class -- `[,;]`.

`(.*)` is greedy and will match as many characters as possible. If you use the regex `a.*c` on a string`abcabc`, it will match the whole string `abcabc`. But `a.*?c` will only match the first `abc`. By adding the `?` after the `*`, we tell it to repeat as few times as possible.

The correct regular expression would be:

```
preg_match_all('#_{2,3}\([\'"](.*?)[\'"]\)[,;]#', $text, $matches);
```

[**Regex101 demo.**](http://regex101.com/r/cQ4aI2)

Comment: Not working: Output ERROR!'),' ',__('Please fix following errors!

Comment: works great, what about echo function ___("hello")?

Comment: @jason: Fixed. Added support for quotes, too.

Comment: @jason: I've updated the answer with some explanation. Hope that helps! Also, as a sidenote: although your problem is solved, I suggest you edit your question and improve it in the best way possible. As you can see from the close-reason, some users found your explanation of the problem unclear. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is specifying an underscore followed by 2-3 underscores, because you have typed 2 undescores in the regex. Where you have __{2,3}, change that to _{2,3}.

Also, to match either , or ; after the call, you want `[,;]` rather than `,|;`. Finally, you want to make the match for anything inside the brackets lazy (so it will stop at the first closing bracket instead of covering the 2nd call too) by adding a ? to it.

Solution: `preg_match_all('#(_{2,3}(\((.*?)\)[,;]))#',$text, $matches)`

Comment: Only issue I found is with quotes